# how to select from database based on a match in category?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Is it possible to select certain rows based on a category which matches it when there are multiple categories in the entry?  It's hard to explain so I'll show you.  The row I have in the database looks like this:

```
**article_title**   |   **article_content**    |    **category**

Article-1           |   some content here      |    one,two,three,four
```

So my query looks like this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli_connect, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category='
preg_match(for example the word three)'");
```

Reason why I'm doing that is some articles will be available on multiple pages like page one and page three...so is there a way to match what I'm looking for through the entry in the database row?

Comment: 100500th question on normal database design...

Comment: And **THAT** is exactly why you shouldn't be doing this => `one,two,three,four` for categories. How many times I've seen this type of DB management in the past 2 weeks, where people come and ask us **"how to"**...

Comment: Try and use `WHERE IN` instead. But you really shouldn't be designing your DB structure that way. Now you see how much of a "pain in the neck" it is for you. And believe me, I now what a pain in the neck feels like.

Comment: I just found a way to use "SELECT *...WHERE category LIKE '%three%'".  I see what you mean...is there any problem with how I just wrote?

Comment: That's "one" way of doing it, but you're very limited.

Comment: Ok, I'll stick to that while I'm learning better ways to structure my database

Comment: I suggest you setup different categories/columns instead. It will make your life sooOOooo much easier ;-)

Comment: Yes that would be a problem. Using `%three%` will only find a single word. Using search terms to find a category is a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a more flexible database design.  Create a separate table that holds the one-to-many relationships between (one) article and (many) categories:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `articles` (`article_id`, `article_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Research Normalized Database Design');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article_category` (
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `article_category` (`article_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`category_id`, `category_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Databases'),
(2, 'Normalization');
```

Querying then becomes as simple as:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    articles AS a
JOIN 
    article_category AS pivot ON a.article_id = pivot.article_id 
WHERE 
    pivot.category_id = 2
```

Or do something like:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    articles AS a
JOIN 
    article_category AS pivot ON a.article_id = pivot.article_id 
JOIN 
    categories AS c ON pivot.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE 
    c.category_name = 'Normalization'
```