# Posting values to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to post some values from checkboxes to my database, at the moment it does post a value, but only the last selected value (I currently have 8 checkboxes). Below is what I am using the get the checkboxes:

```
<?
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE active='Yes' ORDER BY name") or die(mysql_error());

 //And we display the results 
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 {
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='attendees[]'";
   echo 'value="' . $result['name'] . '">';
   echo "&nbsp;";
   echo $result['name'];
   echo "<br>";
 }
?>
```

So they successfully show in my form and I can tick as many as I want however when I check the database, only the last one is showing.

I have been reading around and it seems like I need to store them in an array however this is the bit I am finding hard to understand.

Could anyone help me so that all values selected are shown in the DB and not just the last one?

**EDIT:** Too long to fit into a comment so here is the code where it adds the values to the DB

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $score = $_POST['score'];
    $attendees = $_POST['attendees'];     

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO quiz_results (date, score, attendees)
                     VALUES ('$date','$score','$attendees')",$connect);
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'><b>Event Added!</b> - You'll will now be taken back to the previous page.</div>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=4;url=add-result.php>";
  }//end of if($submit).

?>
```

Comment: Please include the code you use to write to the database.

Comment: Like this... ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655355/getting-a-checkbox-array-value-from-post

Comment: You'll want to put their unique id in the array key there, so it's like `attendees[{$result['name']}]`. We'll need to see the code where you write to the DB.

Comment: Hello, I have added that into the question as it was too long to add into a comment. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to look at the structure of the data you're posting. Try `echo"<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>";`. Notice that `attendees` is an array of values.

Comment: attendees needs to be stored in it's own table. Google 'data normalization'.

Comment: Hi showdev, where would that echo go?

Comment: I'd put it directly after `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {`.

Comment: Thanks @showdev, I have added that in and now get the following when I submit the form

Array
(
    [date] => 17.12.2013
    [score] => 52
    [attendees] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value 1
            [1] => Value 2
            [2] => Value 3
            [3] => Value 4
        )

    [submit] => Add a Quiz Result
)
Now in the Database it says 'Array' in the field it used to give a value.

Comment: Yes, `attendees` will be an array of posted values. I recommend viewing the answer from @Dave on this page.

Comment: Thanks @showdev, I'll give it a go. I feel I'm almost there, just missing something that takes the attendees array and transforms it into a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$attendees = $_POST['attendees'];
```

$attendees is an array.  You can't simply store the PHP array in the database without first transforming it into a string.  You could store it as a comma separated list:

```
if ( is_array($attendees) ) {
    $attendees = implode(', ', $attendees);
}
```

But, what happens when an "attendee" has a name that contains a comma?  You could serialize it:

```
if ( is_array($attendees) ) {
    $attendees = serialize($attendees);
}
```

But, in either case, what happens when you want to filter your data based on attendee?  Now you have more problems.

The best way to manage this data (Google:  database one-to-many relationships) is to store the attendees in a separate table that looks something like:

```
quiz_id    attendee_id
1          20
1          42
1          50
```

See my answer at [how to select from database based on a match in category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337153/how-to-select-from-database-based-on-a-match-in-category/20337471#20337471) for an example.

Comment: i @Dave, there will only ever be 8 attendees and none of them will have a comma, I'll never want to be able to filter them so going for your first example will be what I am looking for. How would I go about fitting that into the code I already have? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to give each checkbox a different name.

```
$i=0;

 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='attendees[$i]'";
    $i++
    ...
```

and I hope $_POST['attendees'] is an array?

Then when you insert into quiz results, you will need to loop through the arrays and insert one row of elements at a time into the database, you cant just insert arrays directly like that and expect each element to automatically take their own row.

Hope it helps, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**View**

```
<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE active='Yes' ORDER BY name");


$html = '';

//And we display the results 
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
    $html .= sprintf( '<input type="checkbox" name="attendees[]" value="%d"> %s' , $result['id'] , $result['name'] );
}

echo $html;
```

**When you post the form...**

```
<?php
$attendees = isset( $_REQUEST['attendees'] ) ? $_REQUEST['attendees'] : null;

if( !is_null($attendees)  && is_array($attendees)){


    foreach( $attendees as $attendee){
        // do something.. with attendee id 
    }


    echo 'Ids: '.implode(', ', $attendees);
}
```